# Do not understand overloading in Typescript

Tags: typescript, overloading

I have the following:

```
class Test {
  setContent(data:number, startWith, nameFn, selectedParentID);
  setContent(data:number) {
    return 22;
  }
}

var t = new Test();
t.setContent(22);
```

On the line t.setContent VS code and VS 2013 tell me: "Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target". According to the error I can only call the function with 4 parameters.

The [documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook) does not have any examples for variable amount of parameters so I don't know what the correct syntax here should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation must provide a signature for all possible parameters, so

```
setContent(data:number): number;
setContent(data:number, startWith?: any, nameFn?: any, selectedParentID?: any): number{
  return 22;
}
```

would work

Please look at the 'Overloading' paragraph of this [excellent handbook](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/functions.html) for more details